# "(I'm Gonna) Love Me Again" from *Rocketman* (2019)

Tags: song-title

"(I'm Gonna) Love Me Again" from *Rocketman* (2019) won the Academy Award for Best Original Song.

Can anyone please say, approximately at what time this song is played in the film?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "*where to find ?*" questions are off-topic.

Comment: Why do you want to close this question? Someone who knows can answer this question. If not, it's totally fine. PS: Purpose of the forum is to help each other, not closely following the rules.

Comment: I agree we need to help each other, that's why when people ask a question they should make a maximum effort. If you require help, you also need to help.

Comment: Your question is off-topic for the reason of "*where to find*" but it could also be off-topic for the lack of research. Note that tag "song-title" is also incorrectly used.

Comment: A quick look at [Tunefind](https://www.tunefind.com/movie/rocketman-2019) says **End credits**.

Comment: That link really helped me. Thank you. Instead of saying this is off-topic and put some effort and all that, you could have just provided me the link. I did a lot of Google search but I didn't find the correct link. That's why these kinds of forums exist. I am a student and I would definitely like to give my contribution in the future. Rules and guidelines should be used for helping people, not finding fault in technicality. Either way, thank you for the link.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Any forum have rules and a range of questions, topics that can be asked, or not. If you are asking for help, technicalities and rules are made to improve the chances of getting an answer. Reading the rules ([tour]), writing an on-topic question, finding a correct tag, showing effort are all signs of good will, but also actually improve the chances of someone getting an answer. Please be welcome if you want to contribute in the future.